# How can I get debug builds of a Xamarin Forms iOS app to throw XamlParserExceptions?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My team are currently developing an iOS app using Xamarin Forms. During debug sessions the app launches without any issues. However as the project is nearing initial release we're now attempting to publish Release builds of the app for distribution to QA testers.

When this build is launched, the app crashes immediately. On inspection of the device logs it has thrown a XamlParseException. This is not incorrect, as it appears there is invalid XAML markup in various areas.

The problem is that the publish-to-release->launch->inspect device logs->fix issue loop is pretty much unworkable.

Is there a way of causing these same exceptions to occur during debug?

Comment: Do you mean that when debugging and parsing this XML file there is no crash?

Comment: Yes, when debugging there is no unhandled exception. When running a release build generated from CI, there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: That doesn't make sense if the same code is parsing the same file in both situations, though. Are you sure the release and debug builds are parsing the same file?